# Spring Boot Code generator for RAML

Tags: java

I am looking for a Spring boot code generator, which receives RAML spec files as an input, and in turn, generate a basic Spring boot application covering the basic controllers, mapped with proper paths and examples in responses.

Do we have a plugin or code generator like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find some plugins. When using Maven, we can use the following plugin for RAML generation :

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>com.phoenixnap.oss</groupId>
                <artifactId>springmvc-raml-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <ramlPath>src/main/resources/api.raml</ramlPath>
                    <schemaLocation>/types/</schemaLocation>
                    <outputRelativePath>/src/generated</outputRelativePath>
                    <addTimestampFolder>false</addTimestampFolder>
                    <basePackage>com.mk.raml</basePackage>
                    <baseUri>/api</baseUri>
                    <generateUnreferencedObjects>true</generateUnreferencedObjects>
                    <generationConfig>
                        <includeAdditionalProperties>false</includeAdditionalProperties>
                    </generationConfig>
                    <seperateMethodsByContentType>false</seperateMethodsByContentType>
                    <rule>com.phoenixnap.oss.ramlplugin.raml2code.rules.Spring4ControllerStubRule</rule>
                    <ruleConfiguration>
                    </ruleConfiguration>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-springmvc-endpoints</id>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate-springmvc-endpoints</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

The detailed documentation of the plugin can be found at : https://github.com/phoenixnap/springmvc-raml-plugin